# Equipment or equipments?

Tags: singular-vs-plural, uncountable-nouns, countable-nouns

I am having a conversation with some international learners of English. I am assuming that the term equipment is singular and plural. A chat friend insists that the term equipments is the appropriate term to use, when speaking about this word. The other speaker is using British English in our conversation. I appreciate any feedback that I receive. I have also heard the word furnitures used.

Comment: Why don't you look this up in the easily available dictionaries? Collins, Merriam-Webster, etc. etc. etc. This has no British or American English implications.

Comment: The answer is easily found in any good grammar book, I warmly recommend Michael Swan's [Practical Usage of English](https://www.amazon.com/Practical-English-Usage-Michael-Swan/dp/0194420981). It's an easy read, and it's written for the English language student in mind.

Comment: The reason why learners get this so wrong is because of first language interference. In their native tongue, words such as *advice, furniture, cutlery, information* and *equipment* are COUNTABLE. Look up "countable" and "uncountable nouns" in the [archives](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/uncountable-nouns?tab=Votes), there is a lot of useful information.

Comment: Good feedback. I appreciate the contributions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if there's a difference in British English. But speaking for American English ...

"Equipment" is an uncountable noun. There is no such word as "equipments". One might say, "The equipment in our laboratory includes an oscilloscope and an electron microscope". If you want to distinguish singular and plural, you have to talk about "pieces of equipment" or similar wording. That is, you can say, "We have 4 pieces of equipment", but NOT "We have 4 equipments".

Comment: Same in British English, but Americans sometimes treat 'accommodation' as a countable noun, which we don't.

Answer (score 0):

Some nouns refer to a collection or pool of items.

Even though these refer to multiple physical items, the noun is singular, because we are talking about the items as 1 unit (there is 1 group of items), not multiple pieces.

*Equipment* is one of these nouns.

*Equipments* plural would refer to multiple collections of things that are equipped.  This is a pretty rare usage and typically incorrect.